# Avoid waiting for a terminated thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm having the problem that sometimes a thread that I've started finishes before I call `wait()` on it. It seems that this causes my program to wait for something that is not going to happen again (`notify()`). How can I make sure not to wait for a finished thread?

```
void someFunction() {

  MyThread thread = new MyThread();

  thread.start();

  // .. some stuff that takes sometimes quite long

  synchronized(thread) {
    try {
      thread.wait();
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      // ..
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, it depends *why* you're waiting, but probably something like a `CyclicBarrier`[(link)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) or `Semaphore`[(link)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) could help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the JavaDocs for Thread, it tells you *NEVER EVER* use `wait, notify, or notifyAll` on Thread objects. You should use join()

Comment: I see. Like Afaria posted `join()` did the trick. I didn't know that and it's sad that [this](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/) is the first link google suggests..

Comment: While I agree that calling wait/notify on a Thread object is a bad idea, I am unable to find any mention of it in the [javadoc for the Thread class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) or even the docs for [wait()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) or [notify()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--).  Where is that recommendation documented?

Comment: It is documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-

Answer (score 1):

Instead of wait(), you can use :

```
thread.join()
```

But i dont know the context of your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the "lost notification" problem.  (I.e., you are not using wait() in the proper way.)

When you call `foo.wait()`, you should *always* be waiting for some condition that you can explicitly test.  E.g., like this:

```
boolean condition;

synchronized(foo) {
    while (! condition) {
        foo.wait();
    }
    doSomethingThatRequiresConditionToBeTrue();
}
```

When you do anything that makes the condition true, it should look like this:

```
synchronized(foo) {
    doSomethingThatMakesConditionTrue();
    foo.notify();
}
```

When you do anything that makes the condition false, it should look like this:

```
synchronized(foo) {
    doSomethingThatMakesConditionFalse();
}
```

Notice that:

1. Any code that touches the `condition` is synchronized, and always synchronized on the same object.
2. It is impossible for `foo.wait()` to be called when the condition is true.
3. The `wait()` is called in a loop.

Point (2) is crucial, because `foo.notify()` does not do anything at all if there is no other thread waiting to be notified.  A notification that nobody's waiting for is "lost".  The `foo` object does not remember that it was notified.

Point (3) is important for two reasons.  The main one is, if thread A calls foo.wait(), and then thread B makes the condition true and calls foo.notify(); There's no guarantee that the condition will *still* be true when the wait() call eventually returns in thread A.  Some other thread could have made the condition false again.  This is a very real scenario in many applications.

The other reason why point (3) is important is that the Java Language Specification permits foo.wait() to return even when foo.notify() has not been called.  That's called a "spurious wakeup", and allowing it to happen makes it easier to implement a JVM on certain operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Calling wait on the Thread works some of the time because when a thread terminates it sends a notification to every thread waiting for it. But if the thread has already terminated before your current thread calls wait, then no notification will ever occur.

The advice to use join is correct, and James Large’s answer is correct that your code should wait in a loop with a condition variable. That is exactly what join is doing, if you look in the code for java.lang.Thread.join (where join without an argument defaults to 0, wait(0) means wait without a timeout):

```
public final synchronized void join(long millis)
throws InterruptedException {
    long base = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long now = 0;

    if (millis < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    }

    if (millis == 0) {
        while (isAlive()) {
            wait(0);
        }
    } else {
        while (isAlive()) {
            long delay = millis - now;
            if (delay <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            wait(delay);
            now = System.currentTimeMillis() - base;
        }
    }
}
```

It has a loop where it tests the Thread’s alive flag, and if it is true then it proceeds to wait. If the thread is already terminated then the thread won’t wait, so the case where the current thread waits after the joined thread is finished cannot occur.