# Wait for one thread to finish in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I am relatively new Threading in java and I was trying to do the following work. Two Threads will run. Thread1 will print from 1-10 and then wait while Thread2 will finish printing 11-20 and then finishes its task and notify thread1 to print 21-30 and then thread1 will terminate as well. 
This is the code I have used:

```
private Thread thread = null;
private String name = null;
private static Object obj = new Object();
private static int index = 1;

public childThread(Thread t, String name)
{
  this.name = name;
  this.thread = t;
}
public void run()
{      
try
{
  while (true) {
    Thread.sleep(500);
    if (index % 10 == 0 && index == 10) {
      System.out.println("Waiting for Thread2");
      synchronized (obj) {
        obj.notify();
        obj.wait();
      }
    }
    else if (index % 10 == 0 && index == 20) {
      System.out.println("Waiting for Thread1");
      synchronized (obj) {
        obj.notify();
        obj.wait();
      }
    }
    else if(index == 30)
    {
      obj.wait();
    }


    synchronized (obj) {
      System.out.println(name + " ><>< " + index);
      index++;
    }
  }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

And I am getting the following output:

```
Thread2 ><>< 1
Thread1 ><>< 2
Thread2 ><>< 3
Thread1 ><>< 4
Thread2 ><>< 5
Thread1 ><>< 6
Thread1 ><>< 7
Thread2 ><>< 8
Thread2 ><>< 9
Thread1 ><>< 10
Thread2 ><>< 11
Thread1 ><>< 12
Thread2 ><>< 13
Thread1 ><>< 14
Thread2 ><>< 15
Thread1 ><>< 16
Thread2 ><>< 17
Thread1 ><>< 18
Thread2 ><>< 19
Waiting for Thread1
Waiting for Thread1
Thread1 ><>< 20
Thread1 ><>< 21
Thread1 ><>< 22
Thread1 ><>< 23
Thread1 ><>< 24
Thread1 ><>< 25
Thread1 ><>< 26
Thread1 ><>< 27
Thread1 ><>< 28
Thread1 ><>< 29
```

Based on my current understanding in Java threading.

**if(index %10 == 0 && index == 10)** block will notify the other thread to run and wait while the other completed and same goes for the second one. Now it does not work first time. But when index == 20, thread2 stops working and thread1 continue to print30.

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: `wait()` and `notify()` are low-level synchronization primitives. If you want to wait on an action of another thread, then usually you want either `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` or `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a working code, hope this helps

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Object lock = new Object();
    final Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock) {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
            for(int i = 11; i < 21; i++) System.out.println(i);
        }
    };
    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++) System.out.println(i);
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
            try {
                t2.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            for(int i = 21; i < 31; i++) System.out.println(i);
        }
    };
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

Comment: Your answer may work most of the time, but it contains a fatal flaw:  As @NamshubWriter said, `wait()` and `notify()` are _primitives_.  They are meant to be used in a very specific way.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554127/avoid-waiting-for-a-terminated-thread/27556424#27556424

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental problem here is that you've got a race condition where both threads enter the loop at the same time.

You need to arrange it such that only one is allowed in and the other has to wait immediately.

You might instead try a loop like the following, which is mutually exclusive. One thread will be allowed to enter and begin incrementing and the other has to stop until the first thread calls `obj.wait()`.

```
synchronized(obj) {
    while (index < 30) {
       Thread.sleep(500);
       if (index > 0 && index % 10 == 0) {
           obj.notify();
           obj.wait();
       }
       index++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote one simple code using Shared Objected Class named Counter which will track counter details and wrote two threads ThreadOne and ThreadTwo and Main application class as given below.

As suggested by other,  you can use high level lock object like Semaphore or Lock class.

```
package thread.communication.demo;

public class Counter {

private int count = 1;

private boolean lockTrue = false;

public synchronized void incrFirstThread() {

    while (lockTrue) {

        try {
            wait();

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Counter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    lockTrue = true;

    for (int i = count; i < count + 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    count += 10;

    notifyAll();

}

public synchronized void incrSecondThread() {

    while (!lockTrue) {

        try {
            wait();

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Counter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    lockTrue = false;

    for (int i = count; i < count + 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    count += 10;

    notifyAll();
}
}



package thread.communication.demo;

public class ThreadOne extends Thread{

Counter counter;

ThreadOne(Counter counter)
{
    this.counter=counter;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {

        counter.incrFirstThread();
    }
}
}

package thread.communication.demo;

public class ThreadTwo extends Thread {

Counter counter;

ThreadTwo(Counter counter)
{
    this.counter=counter;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {

        counter.incrSecondThread();
    }
}
}

package thread.communication.demo;

public class ThreadMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Counter counter=new Counter();

    ThreadOne one = new ThreadOne(counter);

    ThreadTwo two = new ThreadTwo(counter);

    one.start();

    two.start();
}
}
```

Output  is as given below.

> [INFO]  [INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @
>   MultiThreading ---
>
> 1Thread-0 2Thread-0 3Thread-0 4Thread-0 5Thread-0 6Thread-0 7Thread-0
>   8Thread-0 9Thread-0 10Thread-0 11Thread-1 12Thread-1 13Thread-1
>   14Thread-1 15Thread-1 16Thread-1 17Thread-1 18Thread-1 19Thread-1
>   20Thread-1 21Thread-0 22Thread-0 23Thread-0 24Thread-0 25Thread-0
>   26Thread-0 27Thread-0 28Thread-0 29Thread-0 30Thread-0 31Thread-1
>   32Thread-1 33Thread-1 34Thread-1 35Thread-1 36Thread-1 37Thread-1
>   38Thread-1 39Thread-1 40Thread-1 41Thread-0 42Thread-0 43Thread-0
>   44Thread-0 45Thread-0 46Thread-0 47Thread-0 48Thread-0 49Thread-0
>   50Thread-0 51Thread-1 52Thread-1 53Thread-1 54Thread-1 55Thread-1
>   56Thread-1 57Thread-1 58Thread-1 59Thread-1 60Thread-1